# how to integrate proguard using https in spring boot maven app using Java 11?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, proguard, proguard-maven-plugin

I am trying to obfuscate a .jar app using Spring Boot 2.3.2, Java 11, Proguard maven plugin 2.3.1 and Proguard base 6.2.2 . My pom.xml looks like this:

```html
          <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2.2</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                 <configuration>

                    <proguardVersion>6.2.2</proguardVersion>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                      <options>
                        <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                        <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                        <option>-dontshrink</option>
                        <option>-dontwarn</option>
                        <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                        SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
                        <option>-keep class !main { *; }</option>
                        <option>-keep class service { *; }</option>
                        <option>-keep class org.apache.** </option>
                        <option>-ignorewarnings</option>
                        <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                            @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                            @org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication *;
                            @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication *;
                            @org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync *;
                            @org.springframework.context.event.EventListener *;
                            @org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent *;
                            @org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils *;
                            @org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException *;
                            @org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException *;
                            }
                        </option>
                        <option>-keepdirectories /src/main/resources/** </option>
                    </options>
                    <libs>.. </libs>
                     <archive>
                                            <manifest>
                                                <mainClass> main </mainClass>
                                                <packageName>package</packageName>
                                            </manifest>
                                        </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

During the execution process, I get this err:

```html
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'classpath:ssl/cert.p12'
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.app.AppGatewayApplication.main(AppGatewayApplication.java:178) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[appGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_proguard_base.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[appGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_proguard_base.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[appGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_proguard_base.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[appGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT_proguard_base.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'classpath:ssl/cert.p12'
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyManagers(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.customize(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServerFactoryDelegate.createBuilder(UndertowWebServerFactoryDelegate.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:266) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'classpath:ssl/cert.p12'
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.loadStore(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:188) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.loadKeyStore(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyStore(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.getKeyManagers(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:110) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:606) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:390) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:331) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:344) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1993) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.SslBuilderCustomizer.loadStore(SslBuilderCustomizer.java:184) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.2.RELEASE]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

I tried to use -keepdirectories option but the file that is not found previously is in src/main/resources/ssl, so I'm not sure if proguard knows how to find it and not obfuscate.

Answer (score 1):

if someone has the same problem, this worked for me:

```
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.p12</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.p12</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

    </resources>
```